# How do I declare a variable as a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is incredibly noobish, but here's an example of what I want:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_file = file() # name required
        self.m_file = None # readonly attribute error
        self.m_file = "" # readonly attribute error
    def ButtonPressed(self):
        self.m_file = open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(), 'r')
```

None of the attempts in `__init__` work.  I tried searching for `python init variable as file` but those keywords brought out a lot of posts not answering the question.

Comment: You can't pre-declare variable types in Python; it's dynamically typed. Whatever you assign to `self.m_file` will be overwritten in `ButtonPressed()` anyway, so it doesn't matter what you do in `__init__`

Comment: You don't declare variables in python. Once it is assigned in `ButtonPressed` you'll have your file.

Comment: What is the actual question? What is your end goal? This is unclear to me.

Comment: I'm 2,500 lines into my first Python program and was under the impression you had to declare all self variables in __init__ first.  Oh boy, I made this a bit sloppy.

Comment: Once you call ButtonPressed you will have access to the file so remove everything from init, just make sure you call the method before you try to access the attribute, also be aware that you can only iterate over a file object once. Also if the file cannot be opened for some reason your app will crash so you should factor that into your logic

Comment: @user3000724: yes. It is generally a good idea, to specify all attribute names in `__init__()`. As the default value for a file, you could use `None` as [@Matt Young suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36185766/4279)

Comment: It's unrelated to your actual question, but in Python 2, I'd strongly encourage you to always write your classes as inheriting from `object` (or some other base class that in turn inherits from `object`) so they will be "new-style" classes, rather than the old-style that was the norm before Python 2.2. If you're just learning Python now, don't even bother learning about how old-style classes work, since they're gone from Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the open() function in ButtonPressed method will overwrite anything done in the __init__ call. I would recommend keeping this line

```
def __init__(self):
    self.m_file = None
```

As this will allow you to check whether the variable is None before attempting to use it somewhere else in the class

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to use the [`open()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). I don't think that you'd want to do this in your constructor, but `open()` is what you're looking for.